# Checkbox в DBGrid

Tags: dbgrid, delphi

Доброго времени суток! Делаю программу на Delphi, где в компоненте DBGrid присутствует логическое поле отображающее два значения (true/false). Как сделать чтобы  вместо текста true/false в поле отрисовывался checkbox? Подскажите...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.kansoftware.ru/?tid=595

Comment: спасибо). Помогло.